# Right clicking matched results in windows 10 search yields no options

Tags: windows-10, start-menu, windows-search

When I search for and find something (e.g. a song) in the start menu of windows 10, then when I right click it, there is only one single option (Open destination). I want the option to choose which program in which i want the file opened.

Is there a work around for this?

Comment: Will you be changing programs a lot? If not you can open the destination and right click there to set the default program.

Comment: @Spokey I have the right default set, but some files I use in multiple programs regularly